# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory during installation

Tags: wordpress, installation

Unable to complete a upload zip file installation of CiviCRM 5.42.1 on Wordpress 5.8.1, I used the File Explorer plugin to get the unzipped files into /wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM. However after turning on error reporting by changing `/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-config.php`, by changing `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);` to true, and adding `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`, then going to the CiviCRM Installer on the side menu, getting:

> Warning:
> require(/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php'
> (include_path='/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/pear/db:/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/pear/log:/home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail:/home/tay
> in
> /home/[User]/public_html/[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM/civicrm/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
>
> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Pursued changing the root directory, thinking that because File Manager only shows me from the [SiteInDevelopment] level, that perhaps the issue is the absolute and not relative path is actually referring to a location it can't see based on that path, but `[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php` doesn't exist, nor does `[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php (directory, and hence no file).

Can anyone confirm the issue is likely the wrong root, and if so how I can alter this?

Comment: did you use https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.42.1-wordpress.zip  to get the zip file?   That should create the directory `civicrm` (all lowercase) and a subdirectory `civicrm` under that.  The installer will then create the `civicrm.setting.php` file in `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/`

Comment: @KevinCristiano - That was the source of the zip file, yes. I created the folder /wp-content/plugins/CiviCRM and then yes, copying that zip files contents via the File Manager plugin had a subfolder with the case you mention in it. Upon clicking activate in Wordpress' Plugins page, I got the `There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.`, and I get this still when clicking on CiviCRM installer link near the top of the wp-admin sidebar.

Comment: It's not finding the files. Any reason for renaming the plug in folder to CiviCRM instead of the default civicrm?  I have never tried that, and although it should work, I would try with the default directory name.

Comment: @KevinCristiano - No reason. I am aware that files+folder names are case sensitive in Linux, which appears to be what Wordpress is running on for this website. Changed to all lower case, reactivated plugin, but same issue remains. I very much think this has to do with part of the discovered absolute path not being accessible, rather than using a relative path, but cannot figure out how to have the installation pages look elsewhere, nor can I seem to confirm this Wordpress install is running under a hosted or VPS setup via GoDaddy (any way you are aware of to tell this through Wordpress?).

Comment: Hi @user66001 the civicrm.settings.php file is created on install so if your installer hasn't run it won't exist.

Comment: If you browse to /[SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/civicrmcivicrm/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php) in your file browser is the file their or located somewhere else? if so where? I'm assuming you've changed the name of the plugin file back to civicrm - I wouldn't recommend changing this.

Comment: @LukeStewart That file is there on the copy I have locally, that I copied to the server (which I have lost access to temporarily). Without that file are we saying the stated error above will result? Also, yes, in [SiteInDevelopment]/wp-content/plugins/civicrm, "civicrm" is no longer capitalised.

Comment: I'd definitely try - once you get access back - just downloading a fresh copy of the plugin from download.civicrm.org/ and unzipping it keeping it with the civicrm as lower case.